# Why does copy constructor work for initialization, but not for assignment?

Tags: c++, oop

we use copy constructor in case of initialization but why can't we use it in case of assignment . Also in the same way , why assignment operation is not implementing when we initialize (and has a copy constructor)

Comment: because construction is construction and assignment is assignment -- they're two different things.  The fact that both use an `=` in the syntax is irrelevant.

Comment: How would the copy constructor you propose behave when using assignment then?

Answer (score 3):

The copy constructor is used to create a new object while the copy assignment operator is used to change an already existent object.

Comment: I think the question asks "why is this happening" and not "what is happening" . Appears to be a meta level language question.

Comment: @AdityaSinghRathore _"Why is this happening?"_ Because _initialization_ and _assignment_ are two different operations.

Answer (score 0):

Construction creates an object where one doesn't exist, assignment updates an existing object.
For instance, construction might acquire some resources, and assignment might need to release them before copying the source object.

In order to do the right thing in both cases, such a unified constructor as you suggest would need to be able to distinguish between construction and assignment, which would essentially make it two separate functions in one body.

This is better handled by having two separate functions to begin with, which is where we are.